# Riverpod not changing state

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I am trying to use Riverpod for Flutter stage management.

I have created a class called UsuarioProvider:

```
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class UsuarioProvider extends StateNotifier<String> {
  UsuarioProvider(): super("No user");

  void cambiarUsuario (String nuevo){

    state = nuevo;
    cambiarEmailUsuarioSP(nuevo);

  }
  cambiarEmailUsuarioSP(String nuevo) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    state =nuevo;
    prefs.setString("email", nuevo);
  }
  recibirEmailSP() async{
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String emailActual = prefs.getString("email");

  }

}
```

On main.dart I have declared the use of the riverpod provider as follows:

```
//riverpod USUARIO
    final usuarioProvider = StateNotifierProvider<UsuarioProvider>((ref) {
      return UsuarioProvider();
    });
    void cambiarUsuario(String nueva) {
      context.read(usuarioProvider).cambiarUsuario(nueva);
    }
```

Now I need to change the state for UsuarioProvider as follows:

```
...
cambiarUsuario(parsed['user']['email'].toString());
...
```

The value for `parsed['user']['email'].toString() = 'mimail@gmail.com'`

but then, trying to get the state for it:

```
child: Consumer(builder: (_, ScopedReader watch, __) {
                var value = watch(usuarioProvider.state);
                print("%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%EMail en Home:"+value.toString());
                if (value == "No user") {
                  value = 'NoClinic'.tr().toString();
                }
                return Text(
                  value.toString(),
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 12.0,
                  ),
                );
              }),
```

I am always getting 'No user', not 'mimail@gmail.com'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where are using `cambiarUsuario` ?, try to add print statement in `cambiarUsuario` to print the value that you use to update the state, just to make sure the provider get it.

Comment: @MohammedAlfateh, I have inserted a print statement: void cambiarUsuario(String nueva) { print("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ENTRO EN CAMBIAR USUARIO:"+nueva); context.read(usuarioProvider).cambiarUsuario(nueva); } and the output is showing the string as it should: /I/flutter (14342): @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ENTRO EN CAMBIAR USUARIO:modestovasco@gmail.com, but the state is not changed

Comment: I mean to print the state , ok i will right as an answer just because the code is unreadable in the comments section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the provider file :

```
import 'package:riverpod/riverpod.dart';

final usuarioProvider = StateNotifierProvider<UsuarioProvider>((ref) {
  return UsuarioProvider();
});

class UsuarioProvider extends StateNotifier<String> {
  UsuarioProvider() : super("No user");

  void cambiarUsuario(String nuevo) {
    state = nuevo;
    cambiarEmailUsuarioSP(nuevo);
  }

  cambiarEmailUsuarioSP(String nuevo) async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
    
    // this isn't necessary and it will case aditional rebuilt
    state = nuevo;
  }
}
```

The screen :

```
class MyConsumerScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyConsumerScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Consumer(
              builder: (context, watch, child) {
                var value = watch(usuarioProvider.state);
                if (value == "No user") {
                  value = 'NoClinic';
                }
                return Text(value);
              },
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 50),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                context.read(usuarioProvider).cambiarUsuario("It work !");
              },
              child: Text("test"),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

make sure the to add the provider scope :

```
void main() => runApp(ProviderScope(child: MyApp()));
```

Comment: let  me try your proposal

Comment: it is working, this is the output:    +4 ms] I/flutter (19288): nuevo is modestovasco@gmail.com 
[        ] I/flutter (19288):  state is modestovasco@gmail.com

Comment: then, why is the state not changing in the Consumer widget?

Comment: This might not make since but it's just a try. Try to use the consumer default constructor or (snippet) rather than given it an under score and scopedreader just (context,watch,

Comment: would you mind to check if the Consumer widget is declared as it should?

Comment: it is on another class, not in main.dart

Comment: I will edit your answer to show you all my code related to the provider on the other class

Comment: Ok, I also would like to know if the usuarioProvider provide is declared as a global variable (not inside any class) or not.

Comment: yes, it is declared insied HomeScreen class, as you may see in my last Edit to your answer

Comment: The provider declaration should be outside of any class just as a global variable.

Comment: let me try please

Comment: No success, remains the same, the Consumer widget is getting "No user" as state, not 'modestovasco@gmail.com"

Comment: Yes, just below the imports.

Comment: Yes I saw the answer just now, I will try to run the same code in my machine and give an update, give me 5 min

Comment: If I change the state directly on the provider class, it works, the state is changing in HomeScreen. It is all a little weird.

Comment: I tried it and it work, however I didn't use `SharedPreferences` but rather than that I added a delay, I will upload all the code.

Comment: Nice, I will wait for you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229529/discussion-between-mohammed-alfateh-and-mvasco).